# Boot RPI3 using alternative USB storage

Tags: boot, sd-card

Is there a better way ( for faster read/ write ), to boot instead of using the microSD slot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the **Raspberry Pi 3** can boot from USB pendrives and harddisks. This is **not** always faster , but
might be more stable since consumer harddisks are not worn down as much by many small random writes as **consumer** SD cards.

*You need to insert an SD card **once** to enable USB Boot !*

Check the official USB Boot instructions [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md).

Comment: But be aware that usb boot is delayed approximately 5s when no mSD card is present until boot attempt from mSD finally times out.